# regarding div and jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a big div and a small div. The big div has the same layout as the small div vice versa. When I hover over the small div, I want everything in the small div to replace everything in the big div. Is there a way to do this? If so, how can I apply this using jquery? Here's an example:

> ```
> <div id="container">
> <div id="header">      <div id="hcontainer">
>     <h1>Test1</h1>
>     <ul>
>         <li>1</li>
>         <li>2</li>
>         <li>3</li>
>     </ul>
> </div>   </div>  <div id="bcontainer">    <div class="first">
>     <h2>Test2</h2>
>     <ul>
>         <li>4</li>
>         <li>5</li>
>         <li>6</li>
>     </ul>
> </div> </div>
> ```

Comment: Can you please post some sample html?

Comment: This question shows little to no research, I'm afraid.

Comment: @fehays -- I've attached some sample code.

Comment: @Calvin - you should still specify some more detail if you expect a good answer.  For instance, which divs should the hover behavior be applied to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#small-div').mouseenter(function() { 
    $('#large-div').html($(this).html());
});
```

Maybe that's what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

While I like Adam's answer, I would add a bit to it.

Since, you probably want to return the div's contents back to the original after you leave:

```
var temp = $("#large-div").html();
$("#small-div").hover(function(){
  $("#large-div").html($(this).html());
}, function(){
   $("#large-div").html(temp)
});
```

**Edit:**
Based on the added code from the poster.  First, change your tags to close properly:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="hcontainer">
            <h1>Test1</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div id="bcontainer">
        <div class="first">
            <h2>Test2</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
                <li>6</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Next, you can add this code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // The content div is passed in as a string jQuery Selector "#bcontainer"
    // The div to Replace is passed in as string jQuery Selector "#hcontainer"
    function replaceOnHover(contentDiv, divToReplace){
        var temp;
        $(contentDiv).hover(function(){
            temp = $(divToReplace).html();
            $(divToReplace).html($(this).html());
        }, function(){
            $(divToReplace).html(temp)
        });
    };
</script>
```

As I don't know which div is which based on your question, here's a way to show it using this page:
If you're using a browser with a console or FireBug:
hit F12
Paste the function contained in my script tag and hit run (or enter in most cases).
Then, call with replaceOnHover("#question-header", "#question");
When you hover over the question header "regarding div and jquery," the text of your question will change to the same as the header, and as you stop hovering it will change back.

Comment: Your code doesn't work.  You need to move the `var temp` line outside of your `hover` functions.

Comment: @AdamTerlson Thanks, got a little mixed up during the copying and changing the div names.  If we declare it outside, we can set it inside, to ensure that each time it is set too.
var temp;
$("#small-div").hover(function(){
   temp = $("#large-div").html();
  $("#large-div").html($(this).html());
}, function(){
   $("#large-div").html(temp)
});

Comment: @Calvin did you need more information or did that solve your issue?
If (moreInfo) { please read fehays comment about specifying the divs et cetera.}  ElseIf (differentAnswerFound) { please let us know } Else { please mark an answer here.}

Answer (score 0):

I would say

```
$('#small-div').mouseenter(function() { 
    $('#large-div').html($(this).html()); 
});
```

as you probably want to do this once, not constantly while hovering.